# Adding attributes to a struts html:text tag?

Tags: jquery, html, struts, struts-1

I'm using Struts to add a text input like so:

```
<html:text property="userId" styleClass="userClass"/>
```

which gives me this:

```
<input name="userId" class="userClass" type="text"/>
```

Now I want to add the attribute `onchange="myFunction"` to this input field. 
Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: What version of Struts 1 are you using? Struts 1.3, for example, includes the `onchange` attribute in the TLD and should work just fine. If you don't want to use unobtrusive JavaScript, or modify the TLD of the Struts version you're using, then Roman's suggestion (using jQuery) or a plain JS approach is your option.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1 doesn't allow dinamic attributes. You can add attributes later in JS.

```
$("input[name=userId]").change(myfunction);
```